# JSP Form with variable object

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring

I have a configuration object that has 7 unique users. It looks like this.

```
public class Configuration extends Entity {
    private Long accountId;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private User Admin;
    private User Owner;
    private User Dev;
    private User Rec;
    private User Valet;
    private User Manager;
    private User Region;
}
```

Now I am populating this objecting inside of my controller and I am handing it through to a JSP.

In the JSP I am trying to populate a form but I am having a hard time getting the variables right.  My form looks like this:

```
<form:form method="post" action="/configuration/${configuration.id}" modelAttribute="configuration">

<form:input type="text" path="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Main Window"/>
<form:errors path="name" cssClass="help-inline alert-error"/>

<form:select path="active" class="form-control">
                <form:option value="true">ON</form:option>
                <form:option value="false">OFF</form:option>
</form:select>
<form:errors path="active" cssClass="help-inline alert-error"/>
</form:form>
```

All users have these two variables however other than these two variables they are very different.  QUESTION: Can anyone give me an idea as to how I am supposed to refer to these objects within the configuration?

For example: `<form:select path="Admin.active" class="form-control">` ?

It is safe to assume I have handed a complete configuration to the jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my question was more of an example.  I had some configuration issues which is what caused my problems.  Problem solved!  Hope this helps someone.